# Two different approaches to writing a function (map vs loop)

Tags: python

SO busy with some code, and have a function which basically takes dictionary where each  value is a list, and returns the key with the largest list.

I wrote the following:

```
def max_list(dic):
    if dic:
        l1 = dic.values()
        l1 = map(len, l1)
        l2 = dic.keys()
        return l2[l1.index(max(l1))]
    else:
        return None
```

Someone else wrote the following:

```
def max_list(dic):
    result = None
    maxValue = 0
    for key in dic.keys():
        if len(dic[key]) >= maxValue:
            result = key
            maxValue = len(dic[key])
    return result
```

Which would be the 'correct' way to do this, if there is one. I hope this is not regarded as community wiki (even though the code works), trying to figure which would be the best pattern in terms of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the most pythonic would be `max(dic,key=lambda x:len(dic[x]))` ... at least I would think ...

maximizing readability and minimizing  lines of code is pythonic ... usually

Comment: From the Zen of Python:   Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

Comment: I wonder why you got a downvote and I didn't ... That doesn't seem fair ... :-(

Comment: The original question is only giving back the key, and it doesn't have a downvote :).

Comment: This response gives back actually the same return as the code above, but see solution below as well.

Answer (score 6):

Another valid option:

```
maxkey,maxvalue = max(d.items(),key=lambda x: len(x[1]))
```

Of the two above, I would probably prefer the explicit for loop as you don't generate all sorts of intermediate objects just to throw them away.

---

As a side note, This solution doesn't work particularly well for empty dicts ... (it raises a `ValueError`).  Since I expect that is an unusual case (rather than the norm), it shouldn't hurt to enclose in a `try-except ValueError` block.

Comment: A small side note, the code actually only returns the key, however your solution is much better in that it returns the key, and the value of the key, to get the actual length you can just len(maxvalue).

Comment: I would use an if-else (instead of try-except) which would explicitly convey the problem in source code rather than leave one wondering "what might go wrong".

Comment: @phkahler -- I disagree.  I assume that an empty dict is an *exceptional* circumstance.  As such, it seems that exception handling is the way to go by definition.  As a side perk, I expect try/except to execute faster as well since you eliminate one test every time.  However, this case is simple enough that either option is viable I suppose ...

Comment: OK, I can buy that argument ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the question you should ask yourself is, what do you think the most important is: code maintainability or computation speed?

As the other answers point out, this problem has a very concise solution using a map. For most people this implementation would probably be more easy to read then the implementation with a loop.

In terms of computational speed, the map solution would be less efficient, but still be in the same [Computational Magnitute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Therefore, I think it is unlikely that the map method would ever have noticeably less performance. I would suggest you to use a profiler after your program is finished, so you can be sure where the real problem lies if your program turns out to run slower than desired.